# RecyclerView | Fastest smoothScrollToPosition animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

The question is based on real scenario, I simplify the use case:

Let's say we have a spinner with values from 0 to 999 and recycle view.
In additional, to the regular recycler swipe option the user also can choose a number from the spinner and the recycler will roll till the index.

**The problem:** It's take a lot of time to scroll the views when the delta between current page and new spinner value is big (for example, we're on position 0 and now the user choose from the spinner 400).

Below is the code (item layout contain textview only):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Spinner spinner;
    List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
    ItemAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // init "database"
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            items.add(i);

        // Spinner
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        // Recycle View
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        adapter = new ItemAdapter();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>
    {

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.tvIndex.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvIndex;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvIndex = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_index);
        }
    }
}
```

**The Question:** How can I perform like "fast scroll" when need to swipe a lot of pages ?

**EDIT:** I'm want animation but short one.

Comment: Did you try calling scrollTo method? It will swipe to the desired position without any animation.

Comment: recyclerView.scrollToPosition(i); you can try this .

Comment: @Arpit Ratan, MPG, it's not help me, because I want a short scroll animation (actually, I'm looking for like viewPager animation)

Comment: recyclerView.scrollToPosition(i-5); and then recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(i); but remember validate this i as per your use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

recyclerView.scrollToPosition(i-5); and then recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(i); but remember validate this **"i"** as per your use.